# How to add a favicon to a TeX/PDF file

Tags: online

Most web sites have a favicon, that gets displayed in the address bar  of a browser. Is it possible to do the same with a PDF file?

Comment: I think this is off-topic, and answered here: [favicon for PDF files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4886423/914686)